# get current displayed images alt at cycle.js

Tags: jquery, html

i'm using `cycle.js` for a tiny slideshow:

```
var $slider = $(".trauringe");
$slider.cycle({
timeout: 6000,
next:   '#next', 
prev:   '#prev',
before: beforePic,
after: afterPic });
```

and the html markup:

```
 <ul class="trauringe" style="width: 690px; height: 395px;">
   <img src="trauringe/1_Trauringe.jpg" style="display: none;" alt="Trauringe 1" />
   <img src="trauringe/2_Trauringe.jpg" style="display: none;" alt="Trauringe 2" />
   <img src="trauringe/3_Trauringe.jpg" style="display: none;" alt="Trauringe 3" />
   <img src="trauringe/4_Trauringe.jpg" style="display: none;" alt="Trauringe 4" />
   <img src="trauringe/5_Trauringe.jpg" style="display: none;" alt="Trauringe 5" />
 </ul>
```

and im trying to figure out how to read the `alt` of the current image like this:

```
function afterPic() { 
      console.log($('.trauringe').find('img').attr('alt'));
        });
```

unfortunetaly this does not work and it displays me only the first, not the current.

Any help much appreciated! thanks

Comment: sorry for the misapprehension, i edited!

Comment: try `$.each()`! here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: the weird thing is i found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/JEqE9/ but i cant get it to work for me!

Comment: try `console.log(this.alt)`

Comment: can you make your jsFiddle and post it here? it would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
function afterPic() {  
     console.log(this.alt); 
}
```

Comment: that was fast and works flawless! thanks for that :) maybe you have a look at my comment above. in the fiddle the solution is another way, but i dont know how! anyways, this works as well!

Comment: @supersize  the reference to the current image is being passed to the callback method, so you can directly call `this.alt` or `$(this).attr('alt')` inside your method .. see my updated answer.